# how to call data by who contains from another table in mongodb nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backend, ejs

I don't know how to explain but I will try.

I have two tables in MongoDB. They are:

-Games

-Players

Two data of games table:

{season: 4, game: 1}

{season: 4, game: 2}

Four data of player table:

{season: 4, game: 1, player: St. Yusuf, points: 100}

{season: 4, game: 1, player: St. Isaac, points: 80}

{season: 4, game: 2, player: St. Yusuf, points: 90}

{season: 4, game: 2, player: St. Isaac, points: 100}

So, they were the datas. And I want to write them to ejs file like this:

Game 1:

St. Yusuf | 100pts

St. Isaac | 80pts

Game 2:

St. Isaac| 100pts

St. Yusuf| 90pts

But when I try to write them, they get writes like this:

Game 1:

St. Yusuf | 100pts

St. Isaac | 80pts

St. Isaac| 100pts

St. Yusuf| 90pts

Game 2:

St. Yusuf | 100pts

St. Isaac | 80pts

St. Isaac| 100pts

St. Yusuf| 90pts

*The sorting of points are doesn't matter. The case is I want to get write the players with only same game numbers, not all games each other...

So, how to fix it? Here is the backend codes:

```
Games.find({}, (err, gamesData) => {
    Players.find({}, (err, playersData) => {
        res.render('score-board', {games: gamesData, players: playersData })
    })
})
```

Here is the ejs codes:

```
<% games.forEach(game => { %>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Player</th>
        <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <% players.forEach(player => { %>
    <tr>
        <td class="player-name"><%- player.player %></td>
        <td class="player-name"><%- player.points%></td>
    </tr>
    <% }) %>
</tbody>
</table>
<% }) %>
```

Here is the Games table's structure:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    season: {type:String},
    game: {type:String}
}, {timestamps:true})

module.exports = mongoose.model('games', Schema)
```

Answer (score 1):

to achieve the result you are looking for you should restructure your tables to something like this:

```
{
    "Games" : [
        {
            "season":4,
            "game":1,
            "Players": [
                {
                    "player" :"St. Yusuf",
                    "points" : 100
                },
                {
                    "player" :"St. Isaac",
                    "points" : 80
                }
            ]            
        },
        {
            "season":4,
            "game":2,
            "Players": [
                {
                    "player" :"St. Yusuf",
                    "points" : 90
                },
                {
                    "player" :"St. Isaac",
                    "points" : 100
                }
            ] 
        }    
    ]
}
```

and your `.ejs` file would look something like:

```js
<% games.forEach(game => { %>
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>Points</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
        <% games.Players.forEach(player => { %>
        <tr>
            <td class="player-name"><%- games.Players.player %></td>
            <td class="player-name"><%- games.Players.points%></td>
        </tr>
        <% }) %>
    </tbody>
    </table>
<% }) %>
```

**Games table schema:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    season: {type:String},
    game: {type:String},
    Players: [
        {
            player: {type:String},
            points: {type:Number}
        }
    ]
}, {timestamps:true})

module.exports = mongoose.model('games', Schema);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I get how to solve the problem. But, how to restructure Games table like this? I've added Games table's schema to the question.

Comment: @yusufcode there you go mate, I've updated the answer with the schema

Comment: Mongodb side is okay but ejs side is error hell... `<% players.forEach(Games.Player => { %>`, `<% games.player.forEach(gp=> { %>`, `<% game.player.forEach(gp=> { %>` non of them are not working...

Comment: @yusufcode yes, let me check the entire code for a sec